# hotkeys with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am saving a form on Alt+S using jquery and i am also checking the required fields. It is working properly but i have one problem. When I press Alt+S before entering the required field it gives me error for the required field and the moment i type anything in the required field then the form gets saved. I want that after error when the fields are filled and if the user again presses Alt+S then the form should get saved.

Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var isAltKey = false;
    var isShiftKey = false;
    document.onkeyup = function (e) {
        if (e.which == 18) isAltKey = false;
        if (e.which == 16) isShiftKey = false;
    }

    document.onkeydown = function (e) {
        if (e.which == 18) isAltKey = true;
        if (e.which == 16) isShiftKey = true;

        //ALT+S
        if (e.which == 83 && isAltKey == true) {
            TriggerSaveButton();
            StopDefaultAction(e);
        }

        else if (e.which == 9 && isShiftKey == true) {
            if (document.getElementById("cmbUnder_OptionList").focus() == true) {
                document.getElementById("txtGroupSname").focus();
                StopDefaultAction(e);
            }
        }

    }
    function StopDefaultAction(e) {
        if (e.preventDefault) { e.preventDefault() }
        else { e.stop() };
        e.returnValue = false;
        e.stopPropagation();
    }



    function TriggerSaveButton() {
        var groupname = $('#txtGroupName').val();
        if ($('#tab2').is(":visible")) {
            if ((document.getElementById('<%= txtGroupName.ClientID %>').value == "") && ($('<%= listboxdestination.ClientID %>').children().length == 0)) {
                ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= reqtxtGroupName.ClientID %>'), true);
                ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= reqlstboxdest.ClientID %>'), true);
                return false;
            }

            else if (groupname != "" && ($("#<%= listboxdestination.ClientID %> option").length != 0)) {
                javascript: __doPostBack('<%=btnaddfrmSave.UniqueID %>', '');

            }
        }
        else {
            if ((document.getElementById('<%= txtGroupName.ClientID %>').value == "")) {
                ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= reqtxtGroupName.ClientID %>'), true);
                return false;
            }

            else if (groupname != "") {
                javascript: __doPostBack('<%=btnaddfrmSave.UniqueID %>', '');

            }

        }

    }
});
```

Comment: can u send me some more code of your form. so would be easy to detect proble..?

Answer (score 0):

As per my opinion , You should be used Jquery Form validation not Requirefield validator of Asp.net.

Currently You using required field validator in your from you can replace this with Jquery client side validation.
so it may be solved your issue.

See the How to validate for using Jquery.

1. [jquery for validation Plugins](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)
2. [formValidator](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/)

Comment: rest is the asp.net form, which is simple with required field validators

Comment: hi, @asifa please Show reference links for your solution. I added two reference links to my Answer..

Comment: I checked out the jquery validation but I am required to work only with asp.net validators. Pls can u help with the same code as above. My asp.net form is http://pastie.org/4012516

Comment: look into this. for form validation example: http://pastie.org/4012638  I have added required field validate for "txtNotes" control , I have added one class "required" for validate the text control ("txtNotes")..

Comment: You need to add Script file for validate the form elements.. 1 for Jquery framework and other for validate plugin.. to your form

Answer (score 0):

The Code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>$(function(){
        $(document).keyup(function(event){
                if(event.which == 65){
                    alert("The Letter A was pressed");
                }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Every key has a numeric value, for example, a is equal to 65 and b is 66(and so on).

http://youtu.be/xXZsTNwfMNc
Here is a tutorial that will show you to use hotkeys with jQuery in detail.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.